# Routing in codeigniter doesn't work with non english characters

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a route that contains non English characters. I'm using something like:

```
$route[rawurlencode('stringWithNonEnglishCharacters')] = "controller/method";
```

On my local server this works just fine but when I upload it to the server, for some reason it works only with english characters. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong or what I need to config?

Comment: Can you show a concrete example?

Comment: $config['permitted_uri_chars'] in config.php, you'll want to modify the regex for whatever characters you're trying to add.  You may to look into mb regex encoding to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used ASCII instead.

**Sample**

```
$route['%E0%B8%9A%E0%B8%97%E0%B8%84C'] = 'controller/method';
```

You will see the URL in ASCII format when copying URL and paste it into the text editor.

**Or**

```
$route[urlencode('Your languages String')] = "controller/method";
```