# How to name Codeigniter controller in Non-ASCII chars to gain SEO friendly URL?

Tags: codeigniter, url, unicode, seo

As standard in Codeigniter
`A Controller` is simply a class file that is named in a way that can be associated with a URI.
And the *Controller Class Name* = *File name* but the first char is *Capitalized*
For example

The URL

```
example.com/index.php/blog/
```

The controller

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
?>
```

My need
In my application we require the URL seems like that

```
example.com/index.php/Non-ASCII-chars-String/
```

So How we gain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you want to fix this thing. You need to understand how CI work and especially router in CI.

I think this is the thing that you want: [Routing in codeigniter doesn't work with non english characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365783/routing-in-codeigniter-doesnt-work-with-non-english-characters)

Sorry about my English.

Comment: Exactly .. so the solution will be `$route[urlencode('Non-ASCII-chars-String')] = "controller/method";`